# Tanget to the curve, but point not on curve?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Question is
Find the $x$-coordinate of all points on the curve
$$y=22x\sin(5x)+55\sqrt{3}x^2+68,\quad \frac\pi{10}<x<\frac{3\pi}{10}$$
where the tangent line passes through the point $P(0,68)$ (not on the curve)
there are two $x$ values what are they?

So the point that's really confusing is me is I got the derivative of the function but how do I get the points when only given a point NOT on the curve??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** (1) For brevity we let $y=f(x)$. You have found the slope $f'(x)$ of the tangent line at the point $(x,y)$ on the curve with $x$-coordinate equal to $x$.

(2) You know that the tangent line passes through $(0,68)$.

(3) It follows that
$$\frac{f(x)-68}{x-0}=f'(x).$$

(4) Solve for $x$. We get "lucky," since $\frac{f(x)-68}{x}$ simplifies nicely.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but i did that and got.$(110 sqrt(3) x +22 (5 x cos(5 x)+sin(5 x)))x=22xsin(5x)+55sqrt(3)x^2+68 -68$. But I dont know how to solve for x now.

Comment: I cannot read what you have written. On the left-hand side we get $22\sin(5x)+55\sqrt{3}x$. On the right-hand side goes the derivative, which is probably a lot simpler than what you wrote, it is something like $110x\cos(5x)+22\sin(5x)+110\sqrt{3}x$. No Wolfram, do some algebra, things will turn out nicely. I have done it myself, it is not hard. But it is very important to not make any mistakes, since almost any mistake will turn an equation that simplifies nicely into a monster.

Comment: What angles have cosine equal to $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$? Recall special angles. The angle $\pi/6$ has cosine$ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so by the shape of the cosine curve the smallest positive angle with cosine $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is $\pi-\pi/6$. That will give you one answer, $5x=5\pi/6$. You can look for others, the next angle with the right cosine is $2\pi-5\pi/6$.

Answer (score 0):

From the equation you give as $y=f(x)$, first write an equation for the tangent line to the graph at the point $(a,f(a))$ in the form $y=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$, and note that the point $P(0,68)$ (not on the graph, as you noted) is supposed to be on that line, so $68=f(a)+f'(a)(0-a)$ -- now solve for $a$.